# Invalid value provided for 'blockDev...roup.globalIdentifier'. while creating VM from Image

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a SL VS with a valid image, and am getting the following error using the python manager. Is there something I am missing. If i am not mistaken, the image should have specified the block devices?

Do you know what I could add to my inputs for the "create_instance" call I made to stop this error? I've already tried specifying the number disks(i.e disks(100,100))

```
<Fault SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue: "Invalid value provided for 'blockDev...roup.globalIdentifier'. A valid global identifier is required for a template.">
```

code snippets:

```
image_list = SL.instance().image.list_private_images(name=k8s_flex_image, mask='id')
host_name = 'XXXXXXX'
vm_instance = SL.instance().vm.create_instance(domain='XXXXXXX.XXX', hostname=host_name,
                                     private=False, datacenter='sjc01', cpus=16, memory=65536,
                                     hourly=True, dedicated=True, image_id=image_list[0]['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending "globalIdentifier" intead "id", you just need to change your mask to: mask='globalIdentifier' and send that value in the create_instance method.